# python ipaddress, get first usable host only?

Tags: python, ip-address

I am using pythons ipaddress module and im trying to get the first usable host only, not all usable hosts

the below gives me all hosts, and when i try to index it i get the below error.

is is possible any other way to just get the first usable host?

Thanks

```
n = ipaddress.ip_network(u'10.10.20.0/24')
for ip in n.hosts():
...  print ip
10.10.20.1
10.10.20.2
10.10.20.3
10.10.20.4
...
>>> for ip in n.hosts():
...  print ip[1]
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: 'IPv4Address' object does not support indexing
>>>
```

the below is also failing

```
>>> print n.hosts()[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: `ip` is already a single IP in the list, what do you expect `ip[1]` to return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hosts()` returns a generator object, which does not support indexing. You must iterate through it.

If you only want the first element, just use `next()`:

```
n = ipaddress.ip_network(u'10.10.20.0/24')
first_host = next(n.hosts())
```

If you want to convert the generator object into a list which supports indexing, you have to call the `list()` function:

```
all_hosts = list(n.hosts())
first_host = all_hosts[0]
```

You can also loop through a generator object like you would a list, as you did in your first code snippet:

```
for ip in n.hosts():
    # do something with ip: this is the IP address, so don't try to index into it!
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Short version:

```
import ipaddress
net=ipaddress.ip_network(u'1.0.0.0/8')
first=str(net[1])
last=str(net[-2])
```

Long version:

This shows 3 ways of computing first and last usable IP addresses
in a CIDR block using ipaddress.

It shows the "right" (fast, space efficient way to do this)
and two others using the hosts iterator which turn out to
illustrate a classic space time tradeoff.

```
import ipaddress
import time
import sys

#
# The fast, memory efficient way
#

start = time.time()

net=ipaddress.ip_network(u'1.0.0.0/8')
first=str(net[1])
last=str(net[-2])

stop = time.time()
seconds=stop-start
size=sys.getsizeof(net)

print("First Host: %s, Last Host: %s, Seconds: %.4f, Size (Mb): %d" % (first,last, seconds, size/(1024**2)))

#
# Space efficient, but slow
#

start = time.time()

net=ipaddress.ip_network(u'1.0.0.0/8')
iterator=ipaddress.ip_network(u'1.0.0.0/8').hosts()
first = last = next(iterator, None)
for last in iterator:
    pass
first=str(first)
last=str(last)

stop = time.time()
seconds=stop-start
size=sys.getsizeof(net)

print("First Host: %s, Last Host: %s, Seconds: %.4f, Size (Mb): %d" % (first,last, seconds, size/(1024**2)))



#
# Memory hog and slow, the worst of both worlds.
#

start = time.time()

hosts=list(ipaddress.ip_network(u'1.0.0.0/8').hosts())
first_host=str(hosts[0])
last_host=str(hosts[-1])
size=sys.getsizeof(hosts)

stop = time.time()
seconds=stop-start
print("First Host: %s, Last Host: %s, Seconds: %.4f, Size (Mb): %d" % (first,last, seconds, size/(1024**2)))

First Host: 1.0.0.1, Last Host: 1.255.255.254, Seconds: 0.0000, Size (Mb): 0
First Host: 1.0.0.1, Last Host: 1.255.255.254, Seconds: 8.0086, Size (Mb): 0
First Host: 1.0.0.1, Last Host: 1.255.255.254, Seconds: 11.8096, Size (Mb): 132
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way to get the first host address **especially for "big networks" / small prefix values** is:

```
In [2]: ip_network("10.10.20.0/24")[1]
Out[2]: IPv4Address('10.10.20.1')
```

No need to use the hosts() generator at all. See e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#networks-as-containers-of-addresses about ipaddress Network objects as "containers of addresses". First address within this address space / "container of addresses" is the network address (index [0]). Last address is the broadcast address (index [-1]).

Or you can use the network address & get the first host address by adding 1:

```
In [4]: ip_network("10.10.20.0/24").network_address + 1
Out[4]: IPv4Address('10.10.20.1')
```

Depending on the prefix / netmask you are using, the **hosts() generator can be slow**. If you use

```
list(ip_network("10.0.0.0/8").hosts())
```

the statement creates a list with 2**(32-8) - 2 = 16777214 entries

If I time this statment, it needs > 10 sec to create this host list:

```
In [11]: %time len(list(ip_network("10.0.0.0/8").hosts()))
Wall time: 13.6 s
Out[11]: 16777214
```

If I compare the time needed to get the first address:

```
In [15]: %time list(ip_network("10.0.0.0/8").hosts())[0]
Wall time: 13.6 s
Out[15]: IPv4Address('10.0.0.1')
In [13]: %timeit -n10 -r5 ip_network("10.0.0.0/8")[1]
10 loops, best of 5: 11.8 µs per loop
In [17]: %timeit -n10 -r5 ip_network("10.0.0.0/8").network_address + 1
10 loops, best of 5: 9.16 µs per loop
```

Results: hosts() needs about 14 sec to finish. The alternatives are +/- 10 µs

timeit for a /24 network:

```
In [19]: %timeit -n10 -r5 list(ip_network("10.0.0.0/24").hosts())[0]
10 loops, best of 5: 135 µs per loop

In [20]: %timeit -n10 -r5 ip_network("10.0.0.0/24").network_address + 1
10 loops, best of 5: 9.32 µs per loop
```